# Azerothcore authserver.exe vanished

Tags: azerothcore

Yesterday I compiled AzerothCore on Windows 10 64bit, setup database, configuration files and data files, started authserver, worldserver, heidisql and started to play.

Today when I started authserver it did launch and after a few seconds it closed, I wanted to restart but the file is no longer present, nowhere to be found. I am very confused about that and would appreciate any clue, thank you!

After new build: I did get it work, and again on the second start, authserver exe file goes away.

Comment: Try compiling again.

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem that makes it quit. In order to see what the error is, run it via the terminal so you will see which error is making it fail.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I wanted to try that but the file does not exist anymore, it was removed (I do not know how or why) from its folder. Should I compile again?

Comment: this is weird, no idea why it should have been removed.... yes you can try to compile and generate it again

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me today. I have Avast on my Windows 10 64-bit, just checked my quarantine and it was there.

Simply add azerothcore folders as exceptions and it will be okay :)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34263449)